# Есть ли стилистические или грамматические ошибки?

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

*Наш герой **хвастал ему** обновкой и давал советы по приобретению обуви. Настроение у обладателя резиновых туфель было **шикарное**. Он не уставал повторять,  что счастлив **своей мозоли**, потому что познакомился в кафе с преподавателем математики из местной гимназии – нашел себе настоящего друга!*

1) Хвастал ему, хвастался ему или хвалился ему?

2) Шикарное? Как насчет стиля? Надо заменить слово?

3) Счастлив мозоли? Неужели так говорят? А управление какое: чему или чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Форма *"хвастать ему"* в Нацкорпусе встречается, [**два** примера](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BE%D0%BD&gramm2=dat%2Cm&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) есть. На *"хвастаться ему"* [**шесть** примеров](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BE%D0%BD&gramm2=dat%2Cm&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=), не сказать чтоб сильно больше. Поэтому можно выбрать "хвастался", но и "хвастал" отлично звучит. Есть мнение (первый ответ [здесь](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1637508-hvastatsja-hvalitsja-v-chjom-raznica.html)), что хвастают(ся) с чувством превосходства, а хвалятся "скромнее", что ли. Поэтому если в поведении героя было что-то залихватское, то "хвастал" надо оставить.
2. Поискал также *"шикарное настроение"* в Нацкорпусе, нашёл [один пример](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Да, употребляется нечасто и звучит немного кричаще. Поэтому, если бы у меня возникли сомнения, сказать так или нет, я бы выбрал более нейтральное слово *"отменное".*
3. [Вот](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82&gramm2=dat%2Cm&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) все примеры на *"счастлив(а) тому".* Всего пять штук от трёх разных авторов. Негусто. И целых [144 вхождения](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&gramm1=brev&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82&gramm2=ins%2Cm&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) на *"счастлив(а/ы) тем".* Так что — да, я бы поменял на *"счастлив своей мозол**ью**".*

Comment: Большое спасибо, Артем, использую все ваши ответы. Я даже задумалась на тем, что наш форум - это очень удобный сервис, если на нем можно быстро получить нужную информацию, причем такую интересную и подробную.

Comment: На здоровье, Sharon, рад, что помог! В каком-то роде да. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Из словаря Ожегова:
Хвастать - то же, что хвастаться (*разг.*). *Хвастать обновами.*
Похоже на то, что это слово устаревает. Но даже если не сталкиваться с таким, то воспринимается нормально. Звучит чуть раритетно. Сейчас часто можно услышать: *хвастался перед ним*.
2) Так выражаться - современная тенденция. Хотя у Кузнецова это значение:
*разг.-сниж.* Прекрасный, превосходный.
3) *Счастлив тем* - что-то поспособствовало счастью, вызвало его.
*Счастлив тому* - счастлив какому-то явлению, испытывает счастье по отношению к нему.
Подходит именно это (как в тексте).
Хотя действительно - редкость, чтобы так говорили.
Может, лучше заменить на "рад" (ср.: *рад/счастлив своей мозоли* - то же управление).